# Update Data in Laravel

Tags: laravel

This is my code :

Route:

```
Route::get('/editposts/{id}', function ($id) {
    $showpost = Posts::where('id', $id)->get();
    return view('editposts', compact('showpost'));
});


Route::post('/editposts', array('uses'=>'PostController@Update'));
```

Controller :

```
public function Update($id)
{

    $Posts = Posts::find($id);
    $Posts->Title = 10;
    $Posts->Content = 10;
    $Posts->save();

    //return Redirect()->back(); Input::get('Title')

}
```

and View:

```
            @foreach($showpost as $showpost)

            <h1>Edit Posts :</h1>

            {{ Form::open(array('url'=>'editposts', 'method'=>'post')) }}
            Title : {{ Form::text('Title', $showpost->Title) }} <br> Content : {{ Form::text('Content', $showpost->Content ) }} <br> {{ Form::submit('Update') }}
            {{ Form::close() }}

            @endforeach
```

but when I want to Update my data i receive an error :

http://localhost:8000/editposts/1

Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\PostController::Update()

Answer (score 2):

You need to change route:

```
Route::post('editposts/{id}', 'PostController@Update');
```

Then the form to:

```
{{ Form::open(['url' => 'editposts/' . $showpost->id, 'method'=>'post']) }}
```

Comment: NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Comment: @Mohammad please post the exact route and form you're using now.

Answer (score 0):

Correct the route,specify a parameter

```
    Route::post('editposts/{id}', 'PostController@Update');
```

Pass the post'id as paramater

```
  {{ Form::open(array('url'=>'editposts/'.$post->id, 'method'=>'post')) }}

        Title : {{ Form::text('Title', $showpost->Title) }} <br> Content : {{ Form::text('Content', $showpost->Content ) }} <br> {{ 

        Form::submit('Update') }}
   {{ Form::close() }}
```

Notice **$post->id**

Comment: NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Answer (score 0):

Change your post route to:

```
Route::post('/editposts/{id}', 'PostController@Update');
```

Done!

Comment: NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Answer (score 0):

First declare your route:

```
Route::post('/editposts/{id}', array('uses'=>'PostController@Update'));
```

Then update your form url:

```
{{ Form::open(['url' => url()->action('PostController@Update', [ "id" => $showpost->id ]), 'method'=>'post']) }}
```

**This is assuming your model's id column is `id`**

(Optional) You can also use implicit model binding :

```
public function Update(Posts $id) {
    //No need to find it Laravel will do that 
    $id->Title = 10;
    $id->Content = 10;
    $id->save();
 }
```